# Drawing trendlines of a stock

Tags: trading, technical-analysis

I am newbie to the stock market, just experimenting for now. Could you please check whether or not the trend lines I have drawn are correct?

[image: Trend lines]

Comment: Why do you have to make this difficult by redacting the name of the stock? Please make it easy for those who want to answer the question. There's not much to hide. I've already found the name of the stock.

Comment: All trendlines are correct; all of them are useless; technical analysis is basically astrology.

Comment: There is some inconsistency. Why are your lower trendlines staying below the lows but your upper line is going through the may peak?

Comment: Past stock prices do not predict future stock prices.

Comment: These trendlines are fine. On Money.SE there are a lot of people who have no idea about technical analysis. To add to your understanding I would suggest looking at RSI and exponentially weighted  moving averages. I suggest a number of books / ideas on this post https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/47660/technical-analysis-not-working/63336#63336

Comment: Why did you censor the name of the stock? It didn't take me long to figure out that it is the Steel Authority of India Limited (NSE: SAIL).